# Processing hook messages in a thread C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, keyboard-hook

I've got a static global variable.

```
 static std::string buffer = "";
```

In main I am using SetWindosHookEx to create a system wide hook which will act on certain mouse clicks.

```
HHOOK keyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyHookProc, hInstance, 0);
```

However I don't want my main program waiting for messages to be processed on the main thread. So I create a new thread and detach it with the function to process messages.

```
void help::runThread(){
 std::thread messages(&help::sendMessage, this);
 messages.detach():
}

void helper::sendMessage(){
MSG message;
while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);
}
}
```

I want to record which mouse clicks are pressed (left/right) and append the string left/right to the static/global string from within my detached thread.

Then my keyHookProc is where it appends the strings to the static global variable.
This works if I do it without using the thread to handle the messages.

Is this possible to do with a thread or does the hook message processing need to be from main thread?

Comment: Yes, it is. But if your global variable is not read-only i'd recommend adding a global `mutex` and using `unique_lock` each time you modify it's value. Post more code .

Comment: Also, note that you must call SetWindowsHookEx() from the thread you want to receive the messages.  If you create the hook on the main thread as your question suggests, the messages will go to the main thread.